# Display PostgreSQL tables contents in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

EDIT: Fixed it! in models.py I had to add this to point it to the right table as it uses the folder name as a prefix.

```
class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tablename'
```

I'm looking to display the contents of a postgres table in Django. Clearly I'm doing something wrong but can not figure out why the data won't show.

Below is what I have so far, the tables headers show but there is no data or any error messages. Checked the table in pgAdmin and there is plenty of data there.

```
# models.py 

from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class SensorData(models.Model):
    device_name = models.TextField()
    sensor_type = models.TextField()
    sensor_data = models.SmallIntegerField()
    sensor_date = models.DateTimeField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_name
```

```
# views.py 

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import SensorData

# Create your views here.

class ErrorView(ListView):
    model = SensorData
    template_name = 'errors.html'
```

```
# urls.py 

from django.urls import path
from .views import ErrorView

urlpatterns = [
    path('errors/', ErrorView.as_view(), name='errors'),
    path('', ErrorView.as_view(), name='errors'),
]
```

```
# errors.html 
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{%block content %}

<section class ='infoContainer'>
    <div id = 'sensorInfo'>
        <h2> Error Information </h2>
        <table id = "deviceTable">
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Device </strong></th>
                <th><strong>Sensor Type </strong></th>
                <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Information</strong></th>
            </tr>

            {% for error in object_list %}
                
            <tr>     
                <td> {{error.device_name}} </td>
                <td> {{error.sensor_type}} </td>
                <td> {{error.sensor_date}} </td>
                <td> {{error.sensor_data}} </td>
            </tr>
            
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Maybe override get_queryset method on ListView and return a queryset there?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm new to Django and am unsure on what you mean. Could you provide an example?